# md-autocomplete on clear event in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, material-design, materialize

I'm looking to implement a function when the input box of md-autocomplete is cleared. More specifically, when the 'X' button is pressed to clear the field, i'd like to change a variable (data_on) to false. I looked at the [docs](https://vuematerial.io/components/autocomplete/) and there doesn't seem to be an event for clearing the input. Here is what my component currently looks like:

```
<template>
  <div class="md-auto">
    <md-autocomplete v-model="selected" :md-options="users" :md-fuzzy-search="false">
      <label id="placehold" v-if="selected == null || selected == ''">Start typing...</label>

      <template slot="md-autocomplete-item" slot-scope="{ item, term }">
        <md-highlight-text id="mdtxt" :md-term="term">{{ item }}</md-highlight-text>
      </template>

      <template slot="md-autocomplete-empty" slot-scope="{ term }">
        "{{ term }}" is not currently on file. <a @click="noop()">You can add them here</a>.
      </template>
    </md-autocomplete>
    <div class="md-layout md-gutter">
      <transition name="fade">
        <a class="selectlink" v-if="selected != null && selected !=''" id="link-effect-4" v-on:click="show_data()">Select</a>
      </transition>
    </div>
    <div class="md-layout md-gutter">
      <transition name="fade">
        <span v-if="data_on && selected != null && selected != ''">
          <h1>{{ data_display }}</h1>
        </span>
      </transition>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Do you need to track the click on the button or is it more important when the field is cleared?

Answer (score 0):

Using [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) was the trick.

Here's the function:

```
  computed: {
    data_on () {
      if (this.selected != null && this.selected != '' && this.users.includes(this.selected)) {
        this.view_link = true
        return true
      } else {
        this.data_display = null
        this.view_data = false
        return false
      }
    }
  }
```

If you add: `v-if="data_on"` to an element, it will show/hide based on data_on.